# How to get all the selected checkboxes after they got unchecked

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, jquery-events

Let's start from the beginning...
I have checkboxes in the table and they have unique VALUES.

For example:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="2">
<input type="checkbox" value="3">
```

I want to have an array which will add and remove all the checkboxes in the list depending if they were checked or unchecked by the user (only click event) because in some point I'm resetting all of the checkboxes and I only want to save values when user clicks on it.

I have tried this so far but my code is not doing what I need, because this is giving me a double values when user checks and unchecks twice or more...

```
var selected = new Array();
$('tr td input:checked').each(function() {
    selected.push($(this).attr('value'));
    console.log(selected);
});
```

Do I need to use change event to track user behavior?

Answer (score 3):

You have to update array on checked changed of the checkboxex, Assign common class to checkbox to make select simply and selectively.

*HTML*

```
<input type="checkbox" value="2" class="chk" />
<input type="checkbox" value="3" class="chk" />
```

*Javascript*

```
var selected;
$('.chk').change(function(){
   selected = new Array();
   $('tr td input:checked').each(function() {
      selected.push($(this).attr('value'));
      console.log(selected);
});
```

Comment: this approach will continue to append to the same array and won't solve the duplicate value issue the OP was asking about

Comment: Thanks for pointing, I put the the array creation in event now

Answer (score 2):

You can use the click() handler for this

```
var selected = new Array();

$(':checkbox').click(function(){
   selected.splice(0, selected.length); // emptying last array so to avoid multiple values
   $('tr td input:checked').each(function() {
       selected.push($(this).attr('value'));
       console.log(selected);
   });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this also, this will remove elements from array by unchecking checkboxes..

```
var selected = new Array();
$('input:checkbox').change(function() {
    if(this.checked)
      selected.push($(this).attr('value'));
    else
      selected.splice(selected.indexOf(this.value),1);

      console.log(selected);
});
```

#### Fiddle

Comment: your fiddle seems to be working but when I put it in my code `.change()` event is not being triggered. Any idea?

Comment: You might have selector problem

Comment: hmm selector is working in my question...I have put this `tr td input:checkbox` even tried it with the class name and nothing...

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there is a better way to do this but here's some code a threw together real quick that should work for you.

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
var chkArray = [];

function addCheckBox() {
  var chk1 = document.getElementById('1').checked;
  var chk2 = document.getElementById('2').checked;
  var chk3 = document.getElementById('3').checked;
  var chk4 = document.getElementById('4').checked;

  if(chk1 == true && chkArray.indexOf(1) == -1) {  
    chkArray.push(1);
    alert('Added 1');
  }else if(chk2 == true && chkArray.indexOf(2) == -1) {
    chkArray.push(2);
    alert('Added 2');  
  }else if(chk3 == true && chkArray.indexOf(3) == -1) { 
    chkArray.push(3);
    alert('Added 3');
  }else if(chk4 == true && chkArray.indexOf(4) == -1) { 
    chkArray.push(4);
    alert('Added 4');
  }
}
</script>
</head>
<body onClick="addCheckBox();">
<input type="checkbox" value="2" id="1">
<input type="checkbox" value="3" id="2">
<input type="checkbox" value="4" id="3">
<input type="checkbox" value="5" id="4">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

**HTML:**

```
<input type="checkbox" name="test[]" value="1"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="test[]" value="2"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="test[]" value="3"/>
```

**JS:**

```
var recorder = [];
$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function(){
    var checkboxs = document.getElementsByName("test[]");
    recorder=new Array();
    for(var i=0;i<checkboxs.length;i++){
        if(checkboxs[i].checked){
            recorder.push(checkboxs[i].value);
        }
    }
    console.log(recorder);
});
```

And [JSfiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8wQHF/1/)

Hope this is helpful for you.